# Gracefully terminate a request based service on server

Tags: web-development, server, web-services

In our web application, for each http-request there is a lot of computation that happens on back end. Output can vary from 10 sec - 1 Hour. In the mean time when it is computed, "Waiting.." is shown on the website for the respective user.

But it so happens, that a user might cut down the service in between. So what all can be done on the back end so that the computation can be stopped in between to save resources? What different tactics can be applied here?

And if better (instead of killing the thread directly), then a graceful termination policy should make wonders.

This is using Java - spring jdbc and portlets. Though if it can be shown even for a servlet, I can replicate that to others.

Comment: What is this implemented in? PHP? If so, the default configuration tells the server to abort the script on user-exit (browser close). This CAN be overridden, like this: `ignore_user_abort(true);set_time_limit(0);` which means "don't kill the script if a user exits, and run it for forever seconds" (Change 0 to however many seconds you want it to run maximum).

Comment: This question belongs at serverfault.com but I need more information from you on the technology involved before I would consider moving it there.

Comment: @ionFish No. Java

Comment: @paulmorriss Thanks. Sorry I wasn't aware. Spring jdbc and portlets. Though if it can be shown even for a servlet, I can replicate that to others.

Comment: Actually, it's a better fit for Stackoverflow, but is too vague.